# Filter ICollectionView with more than one filter

Tags: wpf

I'm currently getting an error, and not sure how I can get around it.
I have a ICollectionView that I'm currently trying to filter, and am able to do so, one filter at a time.

Users is my list(of t)

```
collectionView.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, user).firstname().Contains(txtFilter.Text() _
)
```

When I try multiple filters, like so...

```
        collectionView.Filter = Function(m) DirectCast(m, user).accountname.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).firstname.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).lastname.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).isenabled.ToLower.ToString.Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).description.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).lastlogontimestamp.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).whencreated.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).whenchanged.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).oulocation.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).co.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).l.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
                     OrElse DirectCast(m, user).state.ToLower().Contains(txtFilter.Text.ToLower() _
         ))))))))))))
```

**I get an exception, and I don't understand why...**

```
Conversion from string to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

I've fixed this using Linq,it's a bit slower, but it works.

```
result = ocList.Where(Function(w) w.accountname.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.firstname.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.lastname.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.isenabled.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.description.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.lastlogontimestamp.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.whencreated.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.whenchanged.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.oulocation.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.co.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.l.Contains(txtFilter.Text) _
Or w.state.Contains(txtFilter.Text))
```

Comment: Try adding the missing close paren on all the calls to `Contains(whatever.Text.ToLower()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the paren from the end, to the end of each call, fixed the problem. Thanks